# Seperate configuration for GitHub and Local development enviroment on .net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5

I have a c# project. Would like to share it on GitHub. But I don't want to share Google Analytics ID and Other Keys on public GitHub repo. Is there any way to segregate dev source code from GitHub source code copy with the same source files?. I summary, I don't want to add maintinace cost for public GitHub repo.

I don't want to achieve this through App.config or Setting.setting. With these config, I have a lot of dependencies which I can't share with public GitHub.

Please suggest another solution.

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? .NET 5/6 are .NET Core too. Since you talk about `app.config` it must be a .NET Framework 4.x version. The problem is solved in .NET Core by using environment-specific appsettings files and [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)

Comment: In the old .NET Framework there was no great solution. You can specify that a section will load from an external file with the [configsource](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/17/tip-configuration-settings-restarts-sharing-asp-net.aspx) attribute, eg : `<connectionStrings configSource="connstrings.config"/>` and make sure the external file isn't included in the Git repo. You can also have environment-specific config files. You don't have the transparency or ease of overriding settings you have with .NET Core though.

Comment: Even though you mentioned you don't want to use config files (whether it is app.config, appsettings.json is incidental), it's a pity because that exactly what they've useful for.  By default your **secrets** are undefined in the config files.  Developers may provide a local override in app.dev.config/appsettings.development.json and for PROD you can keep the production settings elsewhere private, exactly where that is is up to you.  Maybe a private repo in DevOps, maybe an Azure Key Vault   Best part is CI/CD servers can be configured for this too.